# Text with margins not properly centering?

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7p1v1wt7/5/)

```
<p class="season_date">Season 1 Day 1</p>

<div class="scoreboard">
    <a id="team1_name">Tiannamen Squares</a>
    <img class="team1_logo" src="http://images.sphaxball.com/teams/50/tiananmen-squares.png" title="Tiannamen Squares">
    <a id="team1_score">4</a>
    <a id="time">FT</a>
    <a id="team2_score">3</a>
    <img id="team2_logo" src="http://images.sphaxball.com/teams/50/colorado-stoners.png">
    <a id="team2_name">Colorado Stoners</a>
</div>
```

I know this is kind of a newbie problem, but I can't get these two lines of text to become centered. I want the "Season 1 Day 1" to be properly centered with the "FT" under it. I'm guessing this is because of the margins I have applied, but how do I fix it while keeping the margins?

Comment: Note that `Season 1 day 1` has different then all others. So their centers will be different.

Comment: Are you complaining about the "FT" between numbers is not vertically aligned properly? If so, try adding `vertical-align:middle;` in your CSS

Comment: @Venky No, I want the "FT" between the numbers to be Horizontally aligned to the "Season 1 Day 1" Heres an example of what I want https://jsfiddle.net/fn63mmsw/ As you can see the "FT" is properly aligned with the text above it. However in the Fiddle in the original post, the "FT" is off to the right for some reason. It's not aligned in the center properly